# Find the sides of an AAA triangle inscribed in a circle with known radius

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have all of the angles for a triangle. I want to know the length of each of the sides such that the three vertices will all lie on a circle with a known diameter. How do I do it?

(The application is for a multichannel audio workflow where arbitrary microphone placement needs to be re-encoded in standard surround sound format)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this formula (law of sines):;$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=2 R$$ where $A,B,C$ are the angles of the triangle, and $a,b,c$ are the sides opposite to them and $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle.

Comment: You have the sides and angles inverted

Comment: @jjagmath yes, thanks for pointing out. Edited